# Parse xml files from a directory using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

## I am a newbie in python and I am trying to parse all the xml files in a directory. I wrote the following code, but it's just parsing the first file in the directory, however, it is printing the second file from the directory,but it doesnt parse that file.

```
content_list=[]
print("ID \t\t PMID ")
for file in os.listdir("directorypath"):
        try:
            if file.endswith(".xml"):
              print("XML file found:\t", file)
              print("PMID")
              tree = ET.parse("directorypath"+file)
              doc = tree.getroot()
              ID= 0
              for PMID in doc.iter('PMID'):
                file1 = (ET.tostring(PMID, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
                filename = file1[56:(len(file1))]
                filename2 = filename.split("<")[0]
                print(filename2)
                #ID = ID + 1
                #print(ID, '\t',filename2)
                #content_list.append((ID, filename2))
              #return (content_list)
        except Exception as e:
               print("ERROR", e)
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong (currently this is just a syntax error). Please fix it, so we can know what exactly your code does. Also, you have a `return` statement, but this is not a function. Please complete the code so that it works. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info about how to ask questions. Anyway, in the end, I believe your error (or at least one of them) is that you have `return` inside the `for` loop, so the loop finishes prematurely.

Comment: Hi, I did modify the indentation and also commented the return statement. it did solve one issue but still only the first file in the directory is being parsed and none other.